# Show that $A + B$ is bounded below and $\inf(A+B) = \inf(A) + \inf(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty subsets of $\textbf{R}$ which are bounded below.

Let $A+B = \{x\in\textbf{R}: x = a + b\,\,\text{for some}\,\,a\in A,b\in B\}$. Show that $A + B$ is bounded below and

$$\inf(A+B) = \inf(A) + \inf(B)$$

What about products?

**MY (NEW) ATTEMPT**

If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $a\geq\inf(A)$ and $b\geq\inf(B)$. Consequently, $a + b\geq\inf(A) + \inf(B)$, which means that the set $A + B$ is bounded below. Since it is not empty, it admits an infimum. We shall prove that $\inf(A + B) = \inf(A) + \inf(B)$.

Given that $\inf(A) + \inf(B)$ is an lower bound to $A+B$, it results that $\inf(A) + \inf(B) \leq \inf(A + B) $.

Let us assume by contradiction that $\inf(A + B) > \inf(A) + \inf(B)$.

Then I get stuck. Could someone provide a solution based on contradiction?

On the other hand, if we consider the set $AB = \{x\in\textbf{R}:x = ab\,\,\text{for some}\,\,a\in A,b\in B\}$, then $\inf(AB)\neq\inf(A)\inf(B)$ in general.

Indeed, consider $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [-1,0]$. Then $\inf(AB) = -1$, $\inf(A) = 0$ and $\inf(B) = -1$. Thus $\inf(AB)\neq\inf(A)\inf(B)$.

Could someone please verify if the wording of my proof is good enough?

This question has already been asked  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667426/show-that-infab-infa-infb?rq=1), but I'd like to know if there is another approach to the first part.

Comment: "Given that inf(A)+inf(B) is an lower bound to A+B, it results that inf(A+B)≤inf(A)+inf(B)." 
-- should be $\inf(A+B) \geq \inf(A) + \inf(B)$ (the greatest lower bound is greater than any other lower bound)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my question in order to express my concerns.

Comment: Your "assume for contradiction part" is now off too. You already have $\inf(A)+\inf(B)\leq \inf(A+B)$. So to prove equality the assumption for a contradiction should be $\inf(A)+\inf(B)<\inf(A+B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It was a typo.

Comment: I'm hesitating to provide a solution because you are very close. Rewrite your assumption $\inf(A)+\inf(B)<\inf(A+B)$ as $\inf(A)<\inf(A+B)-\inf(B)$. This tells you something about elements of $A$. Then do the same thing with $B$....

Comment: A small "wording" suggestion: If you are writing this up to submit then I advise not saying "Given that $\inf(A)+\inf(B)$ is a lower bound to $A+B$" since this sounds like you are stating something that is a given assumption rather than something you've just proved. So instead you could write along the lines of "By the argument above ...."